# Email is not getting sent from apex Class if I am using with sharing

Tags: apex, email, permissions, singleemailmessage

I am using invokable apex class for sending email to users when my batch starts and completes, but if I am using with sharing keyword the email is not getting sent although it is showing success in logs.
If I use without sharing than it is working properly. also I have given all the necessary permissions at profile level.

Can anyone explain why it is behaving like this?

```
global without sharing class BatchEmailAlertHandler {
@InvocableMethod(
    label='Send email alert'
    description='Will send the email alert to specified users when a batch cycle starts/completes or fails'
)
global static void sendEmailAlert(List<BatchEmailParameters> params) {
                List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mailsToSend = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    String currentUserId = UserInfo.getUserId();
    User currentUser = [SELECT id, Email FROM User WHERE id = :currentUserId LIMIT 1];
    Contact c = new Contact(Email = currentUser.Email, LastName = 'EmailAlert');
    insert c;
    for (BatchEmailParameters param : params) {
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        List<cgi_collect__Batch_Email_Template_Setting__mdt> emailTemplateSetting = [
            SELECT id, MasterLabel, cgi_collect__Template_Name__c
            FROM cgi_collect__Batch_Email_Template_Setting__mdt
            WHERE MasterLabel = :param.alertType
        ];
        if (emailTemplateSetting != null && emailTemplateSetting.size() > 0) {
            List<EmailTemplate> cycleEndemailTemplate = [
                SELECT Id, Subject, Description, HtmlValue, DeveloperName, Body
                FROM EmailTemplate
                WHERE name = :emailTemplateSetting[0].cgi_collect__Template_Name__c
            ];
            if (cycleEndemailTemplate != null && cycleEndemailTemplate.size() > 0) {
                mail.setTemplateID(cycleEndemailTemplate[0].Id);
            } else {
                System.debug('Email Template not found for :' + param.alertType);
            }
        } else {
            System.debug('Email Template setting name not found for :' + param.alertType);
        }

        mail.setReplyTo(currentUser.Email);
        mail.useSignature = false;
        mail.setSenderDisplayName('Batch Schedular');
        mail.setToAddresses(getRecipients());
        mail.setWhatId(param.whatId);
        mail.setTargetObjectId(c.id);
        mailsToSend.add(mail);
    }
    //Messaging.sendEmail(mailsToSend);
    List<messaging.SendEmailResult> result = Messaging.sendEmail(mailsToSend, false);
    System.debug('Email result :' + result);
    delete c;
    }
```

Comment: You'll need to share your email logic for us to see what's wrong

Comment: @fred I am just preparing the email and sending it. anyways I have attached the logic also if that helps.

Comment: try deleting the Contact in a queueable/future